# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1 when executing "sbt sbt-version"?

Tags: sbt

When I run the command `sbt sbt-version` the first time, the following exception occurs:

```
   at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:32)
   at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:21)
   at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
   [error] java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1
   [error] Use 'last' for the full log.
   Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: What versions of sbt and scala are you using? Have you determined that they are compatible?

Comment: Might be useful to show us your SBT configuration files.

Comment: Could you run `sbt --version` command and post the output here? It doesn't touch the code that causes the SIOOBE and might give us more clues on what the real cause might be.

Comment: Have you sorted it out? What was the issue?